# (Laravel) Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use composer update but I get this error

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                            
 copy(/home/user/.composer/cache/files/nexmo/client/9a77c8d9a60db16a277ace89703c6d841e17b77a.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Comment: Check your `user` and `group` permissions on whatever is running your `webserver`. Make sure that user has the same permissions that are required to write files to `/home/user/.composer`

Comment: What are you operating system? Are you using a VPS or developing in a local environment? Did you have administrator privileges?